# Can I set a bounty on a question I didn't ask?

Tags: support, bounty

Recently I found the exact same question I wanted to ask made by someone else [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787678/python-joblib-parallel-loop-on-windows), however no one has answered the question and in my oppinion it really deserves an answer.

How can I bring attention (i.e. setting a bounty) to get the question answered ?

Maybe this can be a feature to be implemented if it is not.

Comment: You can. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: Just a heads up: a bounty of 50 internet points probably isn't going to make much of a dent in the activity on the question. The question itself is quite poor consisting mostly of a "Hi I'm new and this doesn't work, debug for me please thanks".

Comment: Well, I copy-edited it, correcting tagging, removing fluff and the like, but what @Gimby said holds.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can set a bounty to a question you didn't ask.

In fact, there is no difference between setting up a bounty for one of your question or one from another user.

[mlk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/157672/mlk) pointed out in comments [Stackoverflow's doc for bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).

---

Rules are same for setting a bounty on your own questions:

> Which questions are eligible?
>
> If you don't see the bounty button on a question, one or more of the
>   following applies:
>
> - The question has been asked in the last 48 hours. Give the community a chance to answer your question normally first.
> - You already have three outstanding bounties. You can only have three open bounties at any one time. To start a bounty on this
>     question, you must award at least one of the previous bounties first.
> - The question already has a bounty. To start a second bounty on this question, you must wait for the current bounty to be awarded
>     first.

---

Like for rules, process is the same, you will find a *start bounty* link below each eligible questions - just click it and follow steps.

Because [Stackoverflow's doc for bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) is not up-to-date, here is an image of this link:

[image: start bounty button]

---

I seen some good fellow doing this a lot, like [Josh Caswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603977/josh-caswell?tab=bounties&sort=offered) (*sorry Josh, you was the last guy I stalked :)*).

I never done it myself, but I think it's a good practice for interesting questions that never been answered - especially when question is asked by new users (who can't set bounty or don't want to lose +50 points).

---

Obviously (like said in comments), saying *you can* does not means *you have to*, but it's not the point here.